# Refresh PBI User Permissions using the Azure SDK for .NET (Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.PowerBIClient

Tags: c#, powerbi, azure-sdk-.net

The Power BI REST API has the RefreshUserPermissions call (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/users/refresh-user-permissions) to refresh the user permissions in Power BI. How can I do this using the Azure SDK for .NET (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/?view=azure-dotnet)?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, the management client for power BI doesn't allow you to refresh the dataset. Instead, you can make a REST call from your client application to achieve the same

The AD app requesting the refresh will need **Dataset.ReadWrite.All** permissions

**POST**

```
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{datasetId}/refreshes
```

For more information, you can refer to this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refresh-dataset).

Comment: (If you are not sure what the question author is asking for, you can add a comment under the question to get clarifications before posting. Answers should try to be informative without posing new questions or prompting extended dialogue).

Comment: This call is now available in the Azure SDK for .NET https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powerbi.api.iusers?view=azure-dotnet